# Mocked HttpClient wrapper returning null with xunit

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq, xunit

I'm trying to get used to unit testing with .net core. Unfortunately I'm stuck on getting my `HttpClient` wrapper to return a failed `HttpResponseMessage`.

Here's my test that I'm trying to get working:

```
[Fact]
public async void TestHttpExceptionOnBadRequest()
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Test")))
    {
        var xmlSerializer = new Mock<IXmlSerializer>();
        xmlSerializer.Setup(serializer => serializer.Deserialize(stream)).Returns(new object());

        var httpClient = new Mock<IHttpHandler>();
        httpClient.Setup(client => client.GetAsync("Test"))
            .Returns(Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)));

        var postcodeLookup = new PostcodeLookupService(xmlSerializer.Object, httpClient.Object, "", "");
        await Assert.ThrowsAsync<HttpRequestException>(async () => await postcodeLookup.SearchAsync("", ""));
    }
}
```

Following is my service code. The issue is that `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();` returns null.

```
public async Task<PostcodeContainer> SearchAsync(string text, string container)
{
    // add the query parameters to the query string
    var query = _baseQueryString + "&text=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(text);
    query += "&container=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(container);

    // initiate client & response
    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(query);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    return (PostcodeContainer)_serializer.Deserialize(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());
}
```

And for completeness here is my `IHttpHandler` definition for the purposes of mocking.

```
public interface IHttpHandler
{
    HttpResponseMessage Get(string url);
    HttpResponseMessage Post(string url, HttpContent content);
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(string url);
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync(string url, HttpContent content);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the expected query setup does not match what is generated in the method under test.

```
// add the query parameters to the query string
var query = _baseQueryString + "&text=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(text);
query += "&container=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(container);
```

This causes the mock to return `null` as it does not know what to do when it gets the unexpected query which does not match `"Test"`.

So assuming `_baseQueryString` is also an empty string based on the test in the example the generated query may end up as

```
&text=&container=
```

Therefore that is what the mock should expect to receive in order to perform as expected. Also given that the method under test is expected to error out before the serializer does anything there is no need to set it up to do anything. Just mock it and pass the mock.

You can also have the client expect any query by using `It.IsAny<string>()` in the setup expression.

Lastly, have the test return `Task` if performing acync functions

```
[Fact]
public async Task TestHttpExceptionOnBadRequest() {

    var xmlSerializer = new Mock<IXmlSerializer>();
    xmlSerializer
        .Setup(serializer => serializer.Deserialize(It.IsAny<Stream>()))
        .Returns(new PostcodeContainer());

    var expectedResponse = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    var httpClient = new Mock<IHttpHandler>();
    httpClient
        .Setup(client => client.GetAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(expectedResponse);

    var postcodeLookup = new PostcodeLookupService(xmlSerializer.Object, httpClient.Object, "", "");
    await Assert.ThrowsAsync<HttpRequestException>(async () => await postcodeLookup.SearchAsync("", ""));
}
```